# Sending redis pubsub notification to nodes behind aws-load-balancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis

I have a Redis cluster on AWS. I want to perform some actions on some key events via the pub-sub feature. However there is a situation that a single server might get overwhelmed because of this processing of these actions and also I want to avoid duplication of action. Hence, I need to have some kind of load balancing which will enable me to add/remove nodes for better load-balancing or performing code migrations. Apparently you can't place Subscribers behind an ELB according to: [Using Redis behing AWS load balancer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33125939/using-redis-behing-aws-load-balancer)

So how do I achieve load balancing for actions on Redis pub-sub events?   Or what other options do I have?

One possible but clumsy solution is to create a powerful AWS instance which acts subscriber to the events and passes them to ELB. So this node doesn't do any actual processing but acts as a psuedo master.